# Phasor/Harmonic Addition Formula/Theorem: Why can we take out the frequency out of an complex argument?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

- Harmonic Addition Theorem
- Harmonic Addition Formula
- Phasor Addition Theorem
- Phasor Addition Formula

Those four name can be used as a keyword on google.

 
I haven't known the official name and think that they seems to be equivalent each other.

---

From this paper on page 3

[A Hyperbolic Analog of the Phasor Addition Formula by F. Adrián F. Tojo (July 30, 2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5498.pdf)

> [image]

*Figure 1. Part of page 3 of the paper mentioned.*

---

If I rewrite that,

$$
 \displaystyle \mathrm{a} \ \mathrm{e}^{j \alpha}  + \mathrm{b} \ \mathrm{e}^{j \beta}
  = \sqrt{ \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left( \alpha - \beta \right) } \quad \mathrm{e}^{\ j \  \arg\left[ \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \beta \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( \beta \right) \right] \right]}
$$

So if we take the real part of it, we get

$$
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a}\cos\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \beta \right)
 = \sqrt{ \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left( \alpha - \beta \right) }
 \:
 \cos\left[ \mathrm{arg}\left[ \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \beta \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( \beta \right) \right] \right] \right]
$$

Suppose if $\alpha = \omega t + \phi_1$ and $\beta = \omega t + \phi_2$, then

$$
\begin{align}
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a}\cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)
 &= \sqrt{ \small \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left(\phi_1 - \phi_2 \right) }
 \\
 &\cdot\cos\left[ \small \mathrm{arg}\left[ \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right) \right] \right] \right]
\end{align}
$$

Why can we take the frequency out of the complex argument like this?

$$
\begin{align}
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a}\cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)
 &= \sqrt{ \small \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left(\phi_1 - \phi_2 \right) }
 \\
 &\cdot\cos\left[ \small \omega t + \mathrm{arg}\left[ \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left( \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \phi_2 \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( \phi_2 \right) \right] \right] \right]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$
 \displaystyle \mathrm{a} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \alpha}  + \mathrm{b} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \beta}
  = \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \beta \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \alpha \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( \beta \right) \right]
\label{1}\tag{1}
$

Remember that the complex argument form inside of the cosine is equivalent to \eqref{1}.

Or just use Euler's formula, it's the same.

$
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)
 = \sqrt{ \small \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left(\phi_1 - \phi_2 \right) } 
 \cdot\cos\left[ \small \mathrm{arg}\!\left[ \mathrm{a} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right)}  + \mathrm{b} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)} \right] \right]
$

Factor out the frequency

$
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)
 = \sqrt{ \small \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left(\phi_1 - \phi_2 \right) }
 \cdot\cos\left[ \small \mathrm{arg}\!\left[ \mathrm{e}^{j \omega t} \left( \mathrm{a} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \phi_1 }  + \mathrm{b} \, \mathrm{e}^{j \phi_2 } \right) \right] \right]
$

Remember the [complex argument identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities)

$$
\mathrm{arg}\!\left(z_1 z_2\right) = \mathrm{arg}\!\left(z_1\right) + \mathrm{arg}\!\left(z_2\right)
$$

And also the fact that

$$
\mathrm{arg}\!\left(\mathrm{e}^{j \theta}\right) = \theta
$$

Thus

$
\begin{align}
 \small \displaystyle \mathrm{a} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \, \cos\left( \omega t + \phi_2 \right)
 &= \sqrt{ \small \mathrm{a}^2 + \mathrm{b}^2 + 2 \ \mathrm{a} \  \mathrm{b} \ \cos\left(\phi_1 - \phi_2 \right)}
 \\
 &\cdot\cos\left[ \small \omega t + \mathrm{arg}\!\left[ \left[ \mathrm{a} \cos\left(  \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \cos\left( \phi_2 \right) \right] + j \left[ \mathrm{a} \sin\left( \phi_1 \right) + \mathrm{b} \sin\left( + \phi_2 \right) \right] \right] \right]
\end{align}
$

The point is that, if the cosines on the left side has the same phase part which is separated by addition/subtraction sign, we can take out of it from the complex argument function, hence simplifies it.

Comment: Please critic my answer if it's incorrect.